# lifetime mismatch - Return a referenced mutable variable

Tags: reference, rust, immutability, lifetime

I have structs of different shapes:

```
struct Triangle { points: Vec<u8> }

struct Square { points: Vec<u8> }

struct Pentagon { points: Vec<u8> }
```

I have a trait `CursorReadWrite`:

```
use std::io::Cursor;

pub trait CursorReadWrite {
    fn mwrite(&mut self, writer: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>) -> &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>;
    fn mread(&mut self, reader: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>);
}
```

I can implement it for `Triangle`, `Square` etc

```
impl CursorReadWrite for Triangle {
    fn mwrite(&mut self, writer: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>) -> &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>> {
        //do some work and write the data on Cursor<>
        writer.write(somedata);
        return writer;
    }
    fn mread(&mut self, reader: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>) {
        //read data and do some work and save it in mutable self ( Triangle, Square etc)
        self.points = somedata;
    }
}
```

Call the function like this

```
let csd = Cursor::new(Vec::<u8>::new());
let mut t = Triangle::default();
let new_csd = t.mwrite(&mut csd);
t.mread(&mut new_csd);
```

It gives this error

```
error[E0623]: lifetime mismatch
   |
25 |     fn mwrite(&mut self,writer: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>) -> &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>{
   |                                     --------------------     ----------------------------
   |                                     |
   |                                     this parameter and the return type are declared with different lifetimes...
...
28 |             return writer;
   |                    ^^^^^^^^^^^^ ...but data from `writer` is returned here
```

Comment: Lifetimes 101: know your [lifetime elisions](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision). Consider expanding all lifetimes in `mwrite` as an exercise.

Comment: Why return a reference that was passed into the function? It ought to be available in the outer scope anyway...

Comment: There are multiple other issues in this code: there is no need for a `return` at the end of a function, just remove the semi-colon; results from `writer.write` are deliberately ignored, and this will likely trigger a compiler warning. `mwread` does not even contain a reproducible implementation. You are highly advised to write a proper [MCVE] next time.

Comment: Your code isn't valid Rust. It's missing the `struct` keyword, for one. It generates errors (`method \`mwread\` is not a member of trait \`CursorReadWrite\``, `cannot find value \`somedata\` in this scope`), etc. Please review how to create a [mcve] and [edit] your question to contain it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's not easy to fix your code, because there are plenty of missing pieces, but you might want to re-define `mwrite` with explicit lifetimes:

```
pub trait CursorReadWrite<'a, 'b> {
    fn mwrite(&'a mut self, writer: &'b mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>) -> &'b mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>;
    fn mwread(&mut self, reader: &mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>);
}

impl<'a, 'b> CursorReadWrite<'a, 'b> for Triangle{
    fn mwrite(&'a mut self, writer: &'b mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>) -> &'b mut Cursor<Vec<u8>>{
        ...
    }
}
```

When you have more than 1 input lifetime the compiler can't tell which one you want to pick for the output. Citing [lifetime elision rules](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/second-edition/ch10-03-lifetime-syntax.html#lifetime-elision):

> 1. Each parameter that is a reference gets its own lifetime parameter. In other words, a function with one parameter gets one lifetime
>      parameter: fn `foo<'a>(x: &'a i32)`, **a function with two arguments gets
>      two separate lifetime parameters**: `fn foo<'a, 'b>(x: &'a i32, y: &'b i32)`, and so on.
> 2. (...)
> 3. **If there are multiple input lifetime parameters, but one of them is `&self` or `&mut self` because this is a method, then the lifetime of self
>      is assigned to all output lifetime parameters**. (...)